# Toggle Button value when onClick() is invoked React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When the App starts, the button's text is initially 'c'. When the button is clicked, it goes to toggleDisplay() and checks if `unit === 'c'`. If it's true, then update the `unit` variable to `'f'`. This part works as I tested it using `console.log`. But the unit variable that in inside `<button>` tag is not updating. It's only showing 'c' but it has to toggle between 'c' and 'f'

```
function App() {
...
...
let unit = "c";
const toggleDisplay = () =>{
if(unit === 'c'){
    unit = "f";
    console.log(unit)
}
else{
    unit = "c";
    console.log(unit)
 }
}


return(
    <button className="temp" onClick={toggleDisplay}>
        {unit}
    </button>
)
```

**Ps. This is actually a weather app and the toggle between 'c' and 'f' is the toggle between values of celsius and fahrenheit.**

Comment: Modifying the variable will not trigger a re-render and hence update the button text. Why don't you store `unit` in state?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a state hook to store the unit. In your code, `unit` is being set to "c" every time the component updates.

```
import {useState} from "react";

function App() {
    const [unit, setUnit] = useState("c");
    const toggleDisplay = () => {
        if (unit === "c") {
            setUnit("f");
            console.log(unit);
        } else {
            setUnit("c");
            console.log(unit);
        }
    };
    return (
        <button className="temp" onClick={toggleDisplay}>
            {unit}
        </button>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to create a toggle between two elements

```
import {useState} from 'react'
function App() {
  const [isToggled,setToggle] = useState(false);
  const [unit,setUnit] = useState('c');

  const toggle = () => {
    setToggle(!isToggled)
    isToggled ? setUnit('c') : setUnit('f') // use ternary operator for readability
  }
}
```